# Google and Facebook sign-in via Oculus app in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-signin, virtual-reality, facebook-social-plugins, oculus

I am working on an Oculus App for both Rift and Quest. I am trying to do user sign-in through Google and Facebook but couldn't find any plugin which can work on Oculus app developed in Unity. As far as i think this is because when user sign-in through social platforms in an Android or iOS app they open a webview for third party social platforms. Am i right or can we sign-in a user through social platforms in VR oculus app? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [AuthPair](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/authpair-pair-code-authentication-with-firebase-230690)

> AuthPair is an easy to use device-pairing-solution with Firebase
> Authentication. Easy sign in with any platform through pairing code
> and authentication page -> perfect for all VR/AR apps